# Suppress launching emulator using Android within VirtualBox

Tags: android, android-emulator, adb, virtualbox, android-x86

## Description

I am running `Android-x86 7.1` using VirtualBox. I want to `adb connect` from the host to the guest. I experience a very random behavior when it comes to adb devices. As soon as the virtual machine runs there is a chance that an emulator called `emulator-5554` appears. Sometimes it is listed, sometimes it is not. Connecting to the device using `adb connect 127.0.0.1` results in the following:

- If `emulator-5554` is listed the device `127.0.0.1:5555` is marked `offline` and it cannot be used. `emulator-5554` must be used then.
- If `emulator-5554` is not listed I can use the device `127.0.0.1:5555` without any problem.

`adb devices -l` shows that the emulator is coming from the virtual machine: `device product:android_x86_64 model:VirtualBox device:x86_64 transport_id:1`

## Problem

Even though `emulator-5554` works fine and I can communicate with the virtual machine I cannot rely on this due to I want to automate things. `127.0.0.1` is given by my VirtualBox network configuration. The name `emulator-5554` seems random and might change. Therefore I need to use `adb connect 127.0.0.1` which is not possible when the emulator is online.

## VirtualBox configuration

#### Network settings

- Only adapter 1 is active, adapter 2-4 are not enabled
- `Attatched to: NAT`
- `Port forwarding`:

  - Name: `ADB#1`, Protocol: `TCP`, Host IP: `127.0.0.1`, Host Port: `5555`, Guest IP: `10.0.2.15`, Guest Port: `5555`
  - Name: `ADB#2`, Protocol: `TCP`, Host IP: `127.0.0.1`, Host Port: `5554`, Guest IP: `10.0.2.15`, Guest Port: `5554`

#### USB settings

- `Enable USB Controller` not checked

## Current approach

The current approach is represented by all of the current settings that I have made which still lead to a randomly appearing `emulator-5554`.

Using `adb kill-server` & `adb -s emulator-5554 emu kill` didn't have any effect aswell.

## Question

Is there anything I can do to stop `emulator-5554` from starting up and therefore showing up in my `adb devices`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could solve the problem by using the following port forwarding rules.

- Only adapter 1 is active, adapter 2-4 are not enabled
- `Attatched to: NAT`
- `Port forwarding`:

  - Name: `ADB#1`, Protocol: `TCP`, Host IP: leave blank, Host Port: `55551`, Guest IP: leave blank, Guest Port: `5555`
  - Name: `ADB#2`, Protocol: `TCP`, Host IP: leave blank, Host Port: `55541`, Guest IP: leave blank, Guest Port: `5554`

So the difference to my first approach is leaving blank both host and guest IP as well as choosing different ports for host and guest ports.